# Default value in column which checks wether current year is specified in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a column with default value. The default value is computed as follows:

1. Does Period column (same Table) contain current year? If so, then default value is column 'AnswerA' (same Table)
2. If it doesn't contain current year then the default value is column 'AnswerB' (same Table)

I believe it should be done like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[testComputed](
[Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Period] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
[AnswerA] char NOT NULL,
[AnswerB] char NOT NULL,
[ComputedColumn] char NULL DEFAULT (
    iif( [Period] Contains(CONVERT(nvarchar(5),YEAR(GETDATE()))), [AnswerA], [AnswerB]))
```

The `Period` column is not a `Date` type it's something like this: `01/2019`

I'm not sure if it is possible at all, I hope it's correct but I lack some basic knowledge to execute this.

Comment: You're looking for a computed column. How you determine if `Period` has current year?

Comment: I didn't mention this but I want this column to be editable. And computed column can't be from what I understand.

Comment: No, you can't because it's not allowed in SQL Server, you need a computed column to return the value of one columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the column as:

```
ComputedColumn as (case when Period like concat('%', year(getdate()), '%')
                        then AnswerA else AnswerB
                   end)
```

The `ComputedColumn` is calculated when data is fetched from the table.  So, when the year changes, the value changes as well.

I'm not sure what "editable" means.  The default value for a column cannot contain column references (there might be a way around this using user-defined functions, but that seems like overkill).

Because data is always inserted in the current year, you can use a trigger to assign the value.

However, it might be better to just use an override value column (which is updatable) and then:

```
OverrideValue char(1),
ComputedColumn as (case when OverrideValue is not null
                        then OverrideValue
                        when Period like concat('%', year(getdate()), '%')
                        then AnswerA else AnswerB
                   end)
```